# How to find the global name for using a cljsjs module?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, cljsjs

I'm trying to use the cljsjs/smoothscroll-polyfill library and I have installed it into my project.clj like so: `:dependencies [[cljsjs/smoothscroll-polyfill "0.4.0-0"]]`.
In the page where I want to use it, I have (:require [cljsjs.smoothscroll-polyfill]). 
But I don't know what the global name of this library is so that I can actually use it, i.e., `(.polyfill js/GlobalNameForSmoothScroll)`. What is the global name and how does one find it in general?

I tried using js/smoothscroll, but it didn't work.

Comment: Are you using shadow-cljs?

Comment: no, I'm not. Is it necessary?

Comment: It's not necessary, it's just that shadow-cljs provide a way to require npm modules directly, so you don't have to deal with cljsjs.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the file [smoothscroll_polyfill.ext.js](https://github.com/cljsjs/packages/blob/master/smoothscroll-polyfill/resources/cljsjs/smoothscroll-polyfill/common/smoothscroll_polyfill.ext.js) in the CLJSJS repo it seems it would be just `(js/polyfill)` (eg. `polyfill` is the global name).